# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index on gridview date filter

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I given date parameter to filter data in gridview then it gives me this error

> (Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: index)

on this line  `GVBigbaldailyrpt.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);`

I have rearranged row indexing but not issue resolved

```
private void AddTotalRow(string labelText, string value)
        {
            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F9F9F9");
            row.Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[4] { new TableCell (),//Empty Cell
                                        new TableCell { Text = labelText, HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right},
                                        new TableCell { Text = value, HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right },
                new TableCell { Text = value, HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right }});


                 GVBigbaldailyrpt.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);
        }
```

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: index)

on this line  `GVBigbaldailyrpt.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);`

Comment: Can you show your gridview definition please

Comment: i have five column in gridview and one column is hide

Comment: No I mean the actual code not just a brief description of it

Comment: thanks i have resolved that issue ,row indexing was not properly manage